# Devise won't send email when unicorn worker_processes is 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, unicorn

Here's the start of unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 1
timeout Integer 25
preload_app true
...
```

With those settings, when I try to do a password reset with devise, I get this in my log (lightly edited for security):

```
Started POST "/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-02 13:21:56 -0700
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"(removed)", "user"=>{"email"=>"(removed)@(removed).com"}, "button"=>""}

  Rendered users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.slim within layouts/email (5.2ms)

Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 143.8ms
Unicorn fork complete. ENV['AR_DB_POOL_SIZE']=, ENV['SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY']=, Rails configured to be 5.
```

Note that last line. Unicorn timed out and had to be restarted! (Why?)

Other processes which send email work fine. Only devise seems to be affected.

After many hours of debugging I finally determined that if I change unicorn to use **2 or more worker_processes**, the problem goes away:

```
Started POST "/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-02 14:21:05 -0700
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"(removed)", "user"=>{"email"=>"(removed)@(removed).com"}, "button"=>""}

  Rendered users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.slim within layouts/email (6.9ms)

Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 164.2ms

Sent mail to (removed)@(removed).com (878.1ms)

Redirected to http://localhost:5000/sign-in
Completed 302 Found in 1405ms (ActiveRecord: 24.2ms)
127.0.0.1 POST /password 302 Found Devise::PasswordsController#create HTML 1405.4 (DB 24.2, View 0.0) {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"(removed)", "user"=>{"email"=>"(removed)@(removed).com"}, "button"=>""} {} body: 

Started GET "/sign-in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-02 14:21:07 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as 
  Rendered users/shared/_links.slim (0.7ms)
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application (3.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered global/_header.html.slim (1.4ms)
  Rendered global/_footer.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_airbrake.html.slim (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_notifier.html.slim (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 30.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Success! (How?)

Why I do I have to run 2+ unicorn web workers for devise to work properly? What do I need to fix for devise to work when we only have 1 instance of unicorn??

Thanks for your help!

**Update:** I also asked about this problem on the devise issue tracker: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3614 - we'll see which venue figures this out first :)

Answer (score 0):

Github user [georgeguimaraes](https://github.com/georgeguimaraes) responded to the [issue I opened](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3614) on the devise issue tracker, and after some dialog we discovered that the stylesheet_link_tag method we use to load stylesheets in the email template was causing this problem by somehow making a web call to our web server (which was busy trying to send the email) which caused the whole thing to lock up and die.

Meanwhile, on stack overflow, only 18 people even saw this question. Oh well. Hopefully this investigation helps somebody else someday.